# How can I add api key authentication in nginx proxy?

Tags: docker, authentication, nginx, api-key

Is there a way to configure https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy/ to add basic authentication by hardcoded api keys?

I can only find examples for NGINX Controller and NGINX Plus and I am kind of surprised that there are not many examples out there for this very common use case with open source NGINX.

The example for NGINX Plus is here: https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-plus-as-an-api-gateway-part-1/

Comment: Did read the docs at https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/#config ?

Comment: Yes. It does not mention api keys. Only passoword base and ip whitelisting

Comment: you can try http://tengine.taobao.org/

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I've done on my nginx, it may apply to you

1. I use an "X-APIkey:" header on the client side : `curl -X POST -H "X-APIkey: my-secret-api-key" https://example.com`
2. I have a map defining X-APIkeys authorized value in the nginx.conf
3. I use an internal location to do the key verification using the map in the locations I need to restrict the access to.

```
map $http_x_apikey $api_realm {
    default "";
    "my-secret-api-key" "ipfs_id";
    "this-one-too-is-kinda-secret" "ipfs_cmd";
    "however-this-one-is-well-known" "ipfs_api";
    "password" "ipfs_admin";
}
```

```
 # API keys verification
  location = /authorize_apikey {
     internal;
     if ($api_realm = "") {
        return 403; # Forbidden
     }
     if ($http_x_apikey = "") {
        return 401; # Unauthorized
     }
     return 204; # OK
  }
```

```
location /api/v0/cmd {
     proxy_pass  http://ipfs-api;
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-APIkey, Authorization";
     }
     satisfy any;
     auth_request /authorize_apikey;
     limit_except OPTIONS {
        auth_basic "Restricted API ($api_realm)";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd-api-add;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an if statement works well. You can put it at the server level or on a specific location.

```
map $http_x_api_key $valid_key {
  default 0;
  "key1" 1;
  "key2" 1;
}

server {
    
    location /authenticated {
      if ($valid_key = 0) {
        return 401; # Unauthorized
      }
      proxy_pass http://service;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://service;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```